# Count active ids for each day given a date range in spark sql / Data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark SQL/Dataframe API.
I have the following DF

| user | flight_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| r1 | f1 | 2022-05-01 | 2022-05-30 |
| r2 | f2 | 2022-05-20 | 2022-06-20 |
| r3 | f3 | 2022-06-10 | 2022-06-30 |
| r1 | f4 | 2022-05-10 | 2022-06-25 |
| r1 | f5 | 2022-04-01 | 2022-04-20 |
| r1 | f6 | 2022-06-15 | 2022-06-27 |
| r2 | f7 | 2022-07-01 | 2022-07-20 |

and i wanted to calculate the count of active flights for each day from May 8th to May 10th for a specific user say `r1` . I have looked at Spark Window functions but i could write a SQL / code in scala to get it done .

Expected Output :

| Date | count |
| --- | --- |
| 05/08/2022 | 1 |
| 05/09/2022 | 1 |
| 05/10/2022 | 2 |

I have tried the below query

SELECT
flight_id,
start_date,
split(rpad(' ', datediff(end_date, start_date), ' '), ' ') AS num_active_days_array
FROM
user_flight_table
WHERE
((to_date('2022-05-08','yyyy-MM-dd') between start_date AND end_date) OR (to_date('2022-05-10','yyyy-MM-dd') between start_date AND end_date)) AND rida = 'r1'

to try to get the dates when the flights are active with output like this

| flight_id | start_date | num_active_days_array |
| --- | --- | --- |
| f1 | 2022-05-01 | [, , , , , , , , ... |
| f4 | 2022-05-10 | [, , , , , , , , ... |

wanted to posexplode later to individual counts , but seems i am making it too complicated.

Can some one please help or guide the expected output can be obtained ?

Comment: Please include whatever you’ve tried so far. Additionally, I couldn’t find any dates May 8 to May 10 in your input sataset.

Comment: i have updated the description now @DKNY , May 8th to May 10th is the dates of interest and i wanted to find the flights which are active during those dates , f1 and f4 satisfy that condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query helped solve

```sql
SELECT
   active_flight_date,
   COUNT(*) 
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         explode(active_days_array) AS active_flight_date,
      FROM
         (
            SELECT
               sequence(DATE(greatest(flight_start_date, '2022-05-08')), DATE(least(flight_end_date , '2022-05-10'), INTERVAL '1' DAY) AS active_days_array 
            FROM
               sbschema.air_demand_eligibility 
            WHERE
               greatest(flight_start_date, '2022-05-08') <= least(flight_end_date , '2022-05-10') 
               AND rida = 'r1' ) 
         )
   )
GROUP BY
   1,
   2
```

Comment: Please comment if there is any better approach than this . I think this is not scaling well with large datasets , i see lot of spills inspite of using high 34G executors and the spark job is taking a lifetime to complete

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, datediff, lit, to_date, udf, date_add}
import spark.implicits._
case class C(
    user: String,
    flight_id: String,
    start_date: String,
    end_date: String
)
val source = Seq(
  C("r1", "f1", "2022-05-01", "2022-05-30"),
  C("r2", "f2", "2022-05-20", "2022-06-20"),
  C("r3", "f3", "2022-06-10", "2022-06-30"),
  C("r1", "f4", "2022-05-10", "2022-06-25"),
  C("r1", "f5", "2022-04-01", "2022-04-20"),
  C("r1", "f6", "2022-06-15", "2022-06-27"),
  C("r2", "f7", "2022-07-01", "2022-07-20")
).toDF()

source.show(false)


val dts = udf((startDate: String, days: Int) =>
  {
    val d1 = Seq(startDate).toDF("col_0")
      .withColumn("col_0", to_date(col("col_0")))

    val listDays = Range.inclusive(1,days).toList

    val res = if (listDays.isEmpty) d1 else {
      listDays.foldLeft(d1){(tmpDF, col) =>
      tmpDF.withColumn(s"col_$col", date_add(d1.col("col_0"), col))
    }}

    res.collect().mkString(", ")
  }
)

val res = source
  .filter(col("user") === "r1")
  .filter(
    (to_date(col(("start_date")), "yyyy-MM-dd") <= "2022-05-08" &&
      to_date(col("end_date"), "yyyy-MM-dd") >= "2022-05-08") ||
      (to_date(col("start_date"), "yyyy-MM-dd") <= "2022-05-10" &&
        to_date(col("end_date"), "yyyy-MM-dd") >= "2022-05-10")
  )
  .withColumn("endDatePeriod", lit("2022-05-10"))
  .withColumn("colDays", datediff(col("endDatePeriod"), col("start_date")))
  .withColumn("count", lit(col("colDays") + 1))
  .withColumn("num_active_days_array", lit(dts(col("start_date"), col("colDays"))))
  .select(col("flight_id"), col("start_date"), col("count"), col("num_active_days_array"))

res.show(false)
//    +---------+----------+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
//    |flight_id|start_date|count|num_active_days_array                                                                                          |
//    +---------+----------+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
//    |f1       |2022-05-01|10   |[2022-05-01,2022-05-02,2022-05-03,2022-05-04,2022-05-05,2022-05-06,2022-05-07,2022-05-08,2022-05-09,2022-05-10]|
//    |f4       |2022-05-10|1    |[2022-05-10]                                                                                                   |
//    +---------+----------+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```